# Wordpress HTTP 500 error Localhost is currently unable to handle this request

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, xampp

A bit new to this but I have copied my WP site to local host running on XAMPP. I am getting this error in the logs:

```
[Fri Feb 08 09:02:03.820503 2019] [php7:error] [pid 8832:tid 1976] [client ::1:50133] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Requests_Hooks' not found in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-includes\\class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php:17


Stack trace:

0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-settings.php(215): require()\n

1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-config.php(89): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')

2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')

3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-admin\\install.php(36): require_once('C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...')

4 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\MySite\\wp-includes\\class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php on line 17
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve this?

Thanks in Advance,
Snew

Comment: What is your DocumentRoot setup?

Comment: Try to rename your plugin folder plugin.bak

Comment: DocumentRoot is XAMPP/htdocs/MySite/....   Is this what you need?

Comment: As far as i know `DocumentRoot` must contain an absolute path. So `XAMPP/htdocs/MySite/` is probably a wrong path. My `DocumentRoot` for a local WordPress site looks like `DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/myWordpress"`, I am also using xammp under Windows on my local computer

Comment: @harsh khare -  thanks but this did not work

Comment: @EugeneAnisiutkin Thanks, that is my DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs/MySite    - have I misunderstoof your comment?

Comment: @Snew, You did understand it correctly. It's just that your first comment did't have the full path. The problem is not with `DocumentRoot` and it does not look like a problem in `.htaccess` either. The main problem is that `class-wp-http-requests-hooks.php` should know about class `Requests_Hooks`, but it doesn't `Requests_Hooks` itself comes from `Hooks.php` in `wp-includes` folder. Tracking down where `Hooks.php` is included